# Encoding to Hebrew - PHP, mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using MySQLi to retrieve information from the database. All of my pages are encoded with UTF-8 without BOM, i have 2 pages to deal with, but the main problem is that on the database the information is showed in a regular way - but when i retrieve it it goes like this:

����� ����� - ���?

on the phpMyAdmin panel - the columns are latin1_general_ci (i tried to make it utf8_general as well - same output!).

the "mysql.php":

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xhtml; charset=windows-1255');
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'elenbyin_vadim', 'pass33323', 'elenbyin_vadim');
?>
```

the "index.php", main parts:

```
<?php
include ('mysql.php');
include('functions.php');

if($_GET["lang"] == 'rus')
    $lang = 'rus';
else if($_GET["lang"] == 'heb')
    $lang = 'heb';
else
    $lang = 'heb';
```

......

```
<div class="main_text">
<?

    $result = $mysql->query('SELECT * FROM homepage');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "".$row['title']."<br />".$row['text_heb']."";
    }
?>
</div>
```

can someone help my to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to change the charset for it to work:

```
<?php
    $mysql->set_charset('utf8');
    $result = $mysql->query('SELECT * FROM homepage');
    ...
?>
```

@Class's comment - If you need it in all your pages you can add it to `mysql.php`:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/xhtml; charset=windows-1255');
    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'elenbyin_vadim', 'pass33323', 'elenbyin_vadim');
    $mysql->set_charset('utf8');
?>
```

Also, make sure you set your collation to `utf8_general_ci`.

An older method will be to set the names to utf8:

```
<?php
    $mysql->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $result = $mysql->query('SELECT * FROM homepage');
    ...
?>
```

However according to [`set_charset()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) the first is preferrable:

> Note: This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using
>   mysqli_query() to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended.
>   See the MySQL character set concepts section for more information.

Comment: No problems @LiorElenby, glad to help :)

Comment: wouldn't that be better to add that line in `mysql.php`

Comment: @Class you are right obviously, I will add to answer.. For some reason I missed that OP posted mysql.php code

Comment: Nice to see my (correct) answer being edited in after posting

Comment: @davidkonrad both answers are correct. After reading the docs and figuring your method is preferable I've decided to unite them into a more comprehensive answer with the relevant sources in it.